# Embedding tower in low codimension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

If $F$ is a suitably nice functor from manifolds to spaces, it has a degree $k$ "polynomial" approximation $T_k F$ in the sense of [*embedding calculus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_functors). We set $T_\infty F := \mathrm{holim} T_k F$.

The functor of most interest is the functor of embeddings $\mathrm{Emb}(-,N)$ into a fixed target $N$. By work of Goodwillie, Klein, and Weiss, $T_\infty\mathrm{Emb}(M,N)\simeq\mathrm{Emb}(M,N)$ as long as $\dim N-\dim M\geq3$. One says that "the Taylor tower converges."

I am interested in examples below codimension 3. One such example is knot theory, where it is known that $\mathrm{Emb}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^3)\not\simeq T_\infty\mathrm{Emb}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^3).$ This is the only example I know, and I would like to change this. Specifically, I am looking for examples of manifolds $M$ and $N$ such that either

> 1) $\dim N-\dim M<3$ and the Taylor tower is known *not* to converge, or
>
> 2) $\dim N-\dim M<3$ and the Taylor tower converges anyway.

Comment: Are you asking for examples of specific manifolds $M$ and $N$?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question in order, I hope, to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ben: May I ask you how you come to the conclusion that the Taylor tower for knots does not converge? The only proof I know is fairly indirect. (1) The limit of the embedding tower for long knots is a (2-fold) loop space, e.g. by the work of Sinha. (2) However, long knots do not admit inverses (since usual knots do not admit inverses). (3) Thus, the embedding tower for long knots does not converge. (4) It follows that the embedding tower for knots does not converge. Do you happen to know of a more direct or simpler proof?

Comment: @Ricardo: That was the argument I had in mind, as a matter of fact. It's the only one I've heard, and I don't find it very satisfactory.

Comment: @Ben: A fairly simple related example in which I think one does have convergence is the tower for long embeddings of the line into the plane: the homotopy limit is contractible. I believe this can be proved by direct calculation of the fundamental groupoid: the fundamental groupoid suffices in this case since all spaces involved are 1-types. I must admit I have not yet considered embeddings of the circle into the plane, although the same technique may work here. I will try to think about it.

Comment: I think you can argue that the limit of the tower for knots has uncountably many components--the map from $T_k$ to $T_{k-1}$ is surjective but not injective on $\pi_0$.

Comment: @Tom: Can you please give a brief justification of your last statement about $\pi_0$ of the embedding tower of knots?

Comment: Also, do you guys think the map $\pi_0(K) \to \pi_0(T_{\infty}K)$ is injective?